# Convert XML to CSV automatically in Powershell

Tags: powershell, xml

I've got a few thousand xml files with different formats I'm trying to convert to CSV. I've noticed that in Excel you can open an XML file 'as an XML table', and it will create a schema based on the XML source data. Is there a way to use this Excel functionality in Powershell so I can automate the conversion of these files?

So far, all my research ends up at places where you need to know the schema to parse the files, which is not helpful given the volume I'm working with.

Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<results exportTime="2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST">
    <report label="S Report 5x" slug="L211">
        <record reporting_date_end="03/28/2014" narrative="null">
            <report label="Current Volume">
                <record central_volume_loads="166.79" zone1_volume="233.26" zone3_volume="17.52" zone2_volume="48.94" zone1_volume_pounds="6,671,777" zone4_volume_pounds="9,330,260" zone2_volume_pounds="700,694" zone3_volume_pounds="1,957,789"/>
            </report>
            <report label="Zone1">
                <record imps_percentage="92-94%" total_units="794,007" total_loads="19.85" weighted_average="274.76"/>
                <record imps_percentage="90%" total_units="1,091,657" total_loads="27.29" weighted_average="264.35"/>
                <record imps_percentage="85%" total_units="3,467,452" total_loads="86.69" weighted_average="228.20"/>
                <record imps_percentage="81%" total_units="12,501" total_loads=".31" weighted_average="228.24"/>
                <record imps_percentage="75%" total_units="195,690" total_loads="4.89" weighted_average="187.30"/>
                <record imps_percentage="73%" total_units="0" total_loads=".00" weighted_average=".00"/>
                <record imps_percentage="65%" total_units="1,110,470" total_loads="27.76" weighted_average="166.04"/>
            </report>
            <report label="Zone2">
                <record imps_percentage="92-94%" total_units="891,007" total_loads="22.28" weighted_average="275.26"/>
                <record imps_percentage="90%" total_units="1,813,306" total_loads="45.33" weighted_average="265.04"/>
                <record imps_percentage="85%" total_units="4,378,347" total_loads="109.46" weighted_average="231.04"/>
                <record imps_percentage="81%" total_units="256,289" total_loads="6.41" weighted_average="224.46"/>
                <record imps_percentage="75%" total_units="234,200" total_loads="5.86" weighted_average="183.03"/>
                <record imps_percentage="73%" total_units="0" total_loads=".00" weighted_average=".00"/>
                <record imps_percentage="65%" total_units="1,757,111" total_loads="43.93" weighted_average="165.35"/>
            </report>
        </record>
        <record reporting_date_end="03/21/2014" narrative="null">
            <report label="Current Volume">
                <record central_volume_loads="144.13" zone1_volume="215.06" zone3_volume="27.46" zone2_volume="43.47" zone1_volume_pounds="5,765,336" zone4_volume_pounds="8,602,512" zone2_volume_pounds="1,098,540" zone3_volume_pounds="1,738,636"/>
            </report>
            <report label="Zone1">
                <record imps_percentage="92-94%" total_units="857,233" total_loads="21.43" weighted_average="268.96"/>
                <record imps_percentage="90%" total_units="826,451" total_loads="20.66" weighted_average="260.82"/>
                <record imps_percentage="85%" total_units="3,104,954" total_loads="77.62" weighted_average="223.99"/>
                <record imps_percentage="81%" total_units="8,145" total_loads=".20" weighted_average="248.76"/>
                <record imps_percentage="75%" total_units="136,304" total_loads="3.41" weighted_average="183.96"/>
                <record imps_percentage="73%" total_units="0" total_loads=".00" weighted_average=".00"/>
                <record imps_percentage="65%" total_units="832,249" total_loads="20.81" weighted_average="164.72"/>
            </report>
            <report label="Zone2">
                <record imps_percentage="92-94%" total_units="995,233" total_loads="24.88" weighted_average="270.50"/>
                <record imps_percentage="90%" total_units="1,696,678" total_loads="42.42" weighted_average="262.66"/>
                <record imps_percentage="85%" total_units="3,929,416" total_loads="98.24" weighted_average="227.55"/>
                <record imps_percentage="81%" total_units="269,549" total_loads="6.74" weighted_average="220.32"/>
                <record imps_percentage="75%" total_units="181,125" total_loads="4.53" weighted_average="186.37"/>
                <record imps_percentage="73%" total_units="0" total_loads=".00" weighted_average=".00"/>
                <record imps_percentage="65%" total_units="1,530,511" total_loads="38.26" weighted_average="165.33"/>
            </report>
        </record>
        <record reporting_date_end="03/14/2014" narrative="null">
            <report label="Current Volume">
                <record central_volume_loads="126.80" zone1_volume="186.95" zone3_volume="25.49" zone2_volume="34.67" zone1_volume_pounds="5,071,823" zone4_volume_pounds="7,478,136" zone2_volume_pounds="1,019,473" zone3_volume_pounds="1,386,840"/>
            </report>
            <report label="Zone1">
                <record imps_percentage="92-94%" total_units="738,249" total_loads="18.46" weighted_average="263.39"/>
                <record imps_percentage="90%" total_units="783,791" total_loads="19.59" weighted_average="254.45"/>
                <record imps_percentage="85%" total_units="2,586,286" total_loads="64.66" weighted_average="220.72"/>
                <record imps_percentage="81%" total_units="49,348" total_loads="1.23" weighted_average="191.71"/>
                <record imps_percentage="75%" total_units="131,844" total_loads="3.30" weighted_average="182.33"/>
                <record imps_percentage="73%" total_units="0" total_loads=".00" weighted_average=".00"/>
                <record imps_percentage="65%" total_units="782,305" total_loads="19.56" weighted_average="150.54"/>
            </report>
        </record>
</report>
</results>
```

And here's what Excel turns out:

```
exportTime  label   slug    reporting_date_end  narrative   label2  central_volume_loads    zone1_volume    zone3_volume    zone2_volume    zone1_volume_pounds zone4_volume_pounds zone2_volume_pounds zone3_volume_pounds imps_percentage total_units total_loads weighted_average
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Current Volume  166.79  233.26  17.52   48.94   6,671,777   9,330,260   700,694 1,957,789               
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   92-94%  794,007 19.85   274.76
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   90% 1,091,657   27.29   264.35
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   85% 3,467,452   86.69   228.20
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   81% 12,501  .31 228.24
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   75% 195,690 4.89    187.30
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   73% 0   .00 .00
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone1                                   65% 1,110,470   27.76   166.04
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   92-94%  891,007 22.28   275.26
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   90% 1,813,306   45.33   265.04
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   85% 4,378,347   109.46  231.04
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   81% 256,289 6.41    224.46
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   75% 234,200 5.86    183.03
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   73% 0   .00 .00
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/28/2014  null    Zone2                                   65% 1,757,111   43.93   165.35
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Current Volume  144.13  215.06  27.46   43.47   5,765,336   8,602,512   1,098,540   1,738,636               
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   92-94%  857,233 21.43   268.96
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   90% 826,451 20.66   260.82
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   85% 3,104,954   77.62   223.99
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   81% 8,145   .20 248.76
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   75% 136,304 3.41    183.96
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   73% 0   .00 .00
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone1                                   65% 832,249 20.81   164.72
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   92-94%  995,233 24.88   270.50
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   90% 1,696,678   42.42   262.66
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   85% 3,929,416   98.24   227.55
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   81% 269,549 6.74    220.32
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   75% 181,125 4.53    186.37
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   73% 0   .00 .00
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/21/2014  null    Zone2                                   65% 1,530,511   38.26   165.33
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Current Volume  126.8   186.95  25.49   34.67   5,071,823   7,478,136   1,019,473   1,386,840               
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   92-94%  738,249 18.46   263.39
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   90% 783,791 19.59   254.45
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   85% 2,586,286   64.66   220.72
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   81% 49,348  1.23    191.71
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   75% 131,844 3.30    182.33
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   73% 0   .00 .00
2016-02-11 21:44:04 CST S Report 5x L211    03/14/2014  null    Zone1                                   65% 782,305 19.56   150.54
```

Comment: What are the formats you are looking to convert to CSV?

Comment: @doenoe Sorry, I don't know much about how to describe XML formats.. it's valid XML 1.0. Varying numbers of attributes, nested elements.

Comment: @doenoe I've added a sample, in case that's helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for an XML Schema generator, written in Powershell?

Comment: @WalterMitty I actually wrote a script that creates an xsd file for each xml file, but I'm not sure how to make use of that to get to a csv in the same format Excel creates.

Comment: take a look at the second part of the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409270/how-to-convert-this-xml-to-csv-using-powershell-2-0 you may be able to adapt this code to meet your needs.  At least it will show you how to extract all the fields without knowing the field names in advance.

Comment: @WalterMitty Thanks for responding, I did happen to see that question/answer previously. It does not actually traverse nested elements, just pulls attributes from the lowest level, I took a stab at expanding it to traverse elements as well but didn't make any progress.

Comment: Have you tried using some other tool than Powershell?  I'm thinking of SQL Server.  Loading an XML file into a flat table seems doable, although I've never done it.  Does your enviroment preclude this approach?  Is it too slow?

Comment: @WalterMitty I only tested in SQL Server a bit, but it seems like there's not a good way to dynamically handle disparate schema's. I've shelved this for the moment as I got busy with other things, but hope to circle back before too long.  I thought it odd, given that Excel handles it exactly the way I want, that the same can't be easily achieved in powershell.

Comment: It probably can be, but you have to program it yourself.  And if you don't know the algorithm for traversing the XML tree without a schema, and unraveling all the attributes, it's going to be quite a programming challenge.  I'm surprised that a script that does this isn't on one of the powershell forums.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm going to wait until you circle back to this.

Answer (score 1):

First, your XML is wrong, since it contains elements that are nested inside themselves.
This pertains to the `report` and `record` items.
I have posted a fixed version of the file in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PG0zu4Ux),
where I have renamed the outer `report` and `record` items
to `xreport` and `xrecord`.

Second, since it contains nested elements, they cannot be simply converted
to CSV, since one CSV file can only contain one type of element.

Because of the nesting problem, PowerShell cannot be used on such files,
as it can only do simple conversions.
See the article [Cool powershell: From Xml to Csv in two lines](https://rasor.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/cool-powershell-from-xml-to-csv-in-two-lines/)
for an example.

PowerShell can be hand-coded to convert XML files of a known structure.
For example, see these articles :

- [How to convert this XML to CSV using PowerShell 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409270/how-to-convert-this-xml-to-csv-using-powershell-2-0).
- [xml to csv in powershell](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2014/11/xml-to-csv-in-powershell.html)

A tool that can handle this complexity is the free
[Xml To Csv Conversion Tool](https://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/).

To make it work, you will need to download and unpack the following :

- The interactive tool [version 16](https://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/downloads/get/806200)
- [Xml To Csv Command Line version 1.5](https://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/downloads/get/296995)

Once unpacked in one folder, you could use the interactive program
to test its functioning on one or two files.

If it does what you need, you can use the console variant to batch-convert
files. The format of the batch command is :

```
XmlToCsv.Console.exe -xml <source.xml> -dir <destination-folder>
```

The batch file needs to convert files that have similar structure each to its
own folder, since it will for example convert the above example file into five
files named record.csv, report.csv, results.csv, xrecord.csv, xreport.csv.
As these names repeat for similarly-structured XML files,
the generated files will overwrite each other if they are all directed
to the same folder.

---

If this program does not suite your needs, you will need to write a Powershell
script, that should have two phases :

1. Phase 1 : Create the CSV header by drilling down to the lowest level
2. Phase 2 : Depth-search the entire XML to generate the CSV data-lines.

Your script could loop over the files, for each doing the following :

```
[xml] $xml = [xml] (Get-Content -Path \path\to\file.xml)
[System.Xml.XmlElement] $root = $xml.get_DocumentElement()
```

$root contains the `<results>` node that has these properties :

[image: Get-Member]

Notice that you are looking for items that have MemberType of Property.
Items that have Definition of string are the ones you need to collect,
while a System.Object needs to be drilled again :

[image]

And again :

[image]

This time we need to drill down the item having the Definition of System.Xml.XmlElement :

[image]

Now you have all your properties and can construct the header line.

The script itself will need to use the [forach](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) command to loop through
the attributes of objects and checking the attributes of MemberType and Definition.

I cannot afford the time needed for writing the full script, but hopefully this may get you started.

Comment: I appreciate your response, I'm not sure that repeating element names makes the xml invalid, but that's how it's coming in so I'll have to deal with that.  The behavior I'm trying to emulate is that of Microsoft Excel, it just repeats parent elements and adds fields that may or may not be populated on every line, it's not normalized of course, but it's the output I'm interested in. When a nested attribute with the same name is found, it just adds a number to, `label`, `label2`, etc. It could be that Powershell can't manage this, I was just hopeful since Excel does it so nicely.

Comment: A handwritten PowerShell script can do anything it likes, but a general program will not rename its labels. It might be that you will need first a preprocessor to rename nested items. You need also to tell me if the way the above program works, and especially where it breaks the nested items into five files, is not a game-breaker for you. If it is, please include an example of what is your preferred CSV generated for your example.

Comment: I'd prefer not to break them into separate files, because then I'll just have to write logic to re-combine them.  I pasted the excel output at the bottom of the question, it's not a csv, but the field list shows the structure pretty well. I'll be spending more time with the links provided later. It sounds like, to your knowledge this particular behavior in Excel is not accessible through powershell without rolling out a custom solution.

Comment: "repeats parent fields" sounds like flattening the object to me.  There are several object flattener scripts out there, but I can't tell you anything about them.